# CSS form input outcome as expected, however when viewed on i-OS device - is completely out of alignment, why is this?

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, safari

Keeping this short and sweet; my issue is as follows:
When I view my form in Internet Explorer, Firefox or Google Chrome; the form is displayed as expected.

When I view this form on an ipad (or ipod touch...) the form is not displaying as it should, it becomes 'staggered' across whatever container you place it within (fixed width or auto) and looks completely hideous to say the least! The issue I am having is illustrated in the images linked below.

If someone has some suggestions I could try to force the forms to align correctly within the I-OS platform, that would be grand!

**P.S. -** *When viewed on an Android-based Sony Ericsson Xperia, the form is displayed correctly!*

**Images of issue**
(see images in link below here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c1MF.jpg <- for images)

**HTML used**

```
<p><b>Add a user:</b></p>
<form action='adminmanageuser.php?addconf=yes' method='post'>
<input type='checkbox' checked name='unamecheckbox'>
<br><br><div style='width: auto; text-align:left; display: block;'>
<label class='adduser' for='access'>User Type:</label><select name='access'>
<option value='0'>-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --</option>
<option value='2'>Student</option>
<option value='3'>Teacher</option>
<option value='5'>Admin</option>
</select><br>
<label class='adduser' for='access'>Forename:</label><input type='text' name='fname'><br>
<label class='adduser' for='sname'>Surname:</label><input type='text' name='sname'><br>
<label class='adduser' for='uname'>Username:</label><input type='text' name='uname'<br>
<label class='adduser' for='pass'>Password:</label><input type='text' name='pass'><br>
<label class='adduser' for='year'>Yeargroup:</label><input type='text' name='year'><br
<label class='adduser' for='form'>Formgroup:</label><input type='text' name='form'><br
<input type='submit' style='margin-left: 9em;' value='Add User'>
</form>
</div>
```

**CSS used**

```
label.adduser
{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 7em;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
    display: block
}
input[type='text']
{
    padding: 2px;
    border-color: gray;
    border-width: 2px;
    box-shadow: none
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    width:12em;
}
```

Comment: @Tom Doing that makes them both appear as a list - i.e.
<-label-><br>
<-field-><br>
<-label2-><br>
<-field2-><br>
etc...

How would I go about making the label's align to the left hand side without floating them?

However, this makes both platforms display an identical representation of HTML code - this is obviously the fault in my coding! Thank you very much for pointing it out!

Comment: I would code the fields as a list, each field inside a list item, it will make it much easier to style consistently.